# Datagrid row contents issue

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a TabControl which contains several TabItem's which each contain a bound WPF DataGrid that looks something like (note relevant XAML listed only)

```
<DataGrid Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="6,6,0,0" Name="xxxxGrid" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=xxxxDetailsData}" SelectionMode="Single"
             SelectionUnit="FullRow" 
             GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal"
             CanUserDeleteRows="True"
             CanUserAddRows="True"
             ColumnHeaderHeight="50" 
             SelectionChanged="xxxxGrid_SelectionChanged">
                <DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
                    <validators:xxxxValidationRule ValidationStep="UpdatedValue" />
                </DataGrid.RowValidationRules>
```

I have a Save command that validates all DataGrid's within each TabItem - within the validation I am wanting to cycle thru each DataGrid row of each data grid and check for any errors flagged up by my ValidationRule conditions - to do this I have

```
foreach (T dataGridDetail in dataGridDetailCollection)
{
    DataGridRow row = dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(dataGridDetail) as DataGridRow;
    bool hasError = Validation.GetHasError(row);
    ...
}
```

However when I have *not* already clicked on a tab (remember each tab contains a DataGrid) the "dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(dataGridDetail)" part returns null.  (Note when I have already clicked on the tab to reveal its DataGrid all is fine and the above statement returns a DataGridRow as expected (non-null)

To workaround this I have added

```
if (row == null)
{
    // May be virtualized, bring into view and try again.
    grid.UpdateLayout();

    grid.SelectedIndex = index; //index is incremented for each iteration
    grid.ScrollIntoView(grid.Items[grid.SelectedIndex]);
    row = (DataGridRow)grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
}
```

But this makes no difference - the "grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index)" part returns null

Within the DataGrid XAML definition I've also tried

```
VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"
VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"
```

...but this again makes no difference - I still get a null back

Any ideas ?

Comment: That's make sense as well. `ItemContainers` are containers to hold data and they won't be created unless parent DataGrid render on screen. Moreover, if they are not rendered yet, how can they are eligible to have errors?

Comment: Thanks Rohit - based on that premise, if/when a given DataGrid does get rendered, is there ever the possibility that (via say Virtualization) they (the DataGrid row collection) will become inaccessible/null again (eg. if I go to a different tab and hence the grid on the original tab is taken out of view).  If so can I prevent this via either of the above methods (i.e. UpdateLayout/ScrollIntoView and/or IsVirtualizing/VirtualizationMode)

Comment: Once render, it will return null only in case Virtualization is On for dataGrid and note null will be returned only for items which are not in view. You can set it to false via `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"` and you are good to go then.